# What should be used to avoid aliases in linux?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm creating a program to work with `PostgreSQL` on many different `linux` distributions.

To avoid using aliases (which may contain unneeded arguments like alias `grep='grep --color=auto'`) you can use either `/bin/grep` or `\grep`

I know that `\grep` uses `$PATH` which could be manipulated.

Which one is better and why?

Comment: If you want to be sure of the version you are using, use the full path to the bin file,

Comment: `Which one is better and why?` I do not really understand. If you don't like the alias, then remove it. Aliases is something you should configure in your bashrc for _interactive shell_. So when you "creating a program" you do not care about aliases. I have some `alias`es in my bashrc that remove some opensuse stuff that I don't like.

Comment: You may consider using `unalias -a` to remove all aliases.

Comment: @isxaker : It is unclear what you want to achieve. If compatibility is an issue, you will have to make at least some assumptions on what is common on all the platforms you are running. If you fear that your script will be invoked with some modified environment, then set your environment manually in your script. But what is your overall goal?

Comment: @KamilCuk  I can't remove them cause I'm not an owner of machines. I just have access to work with postgreSql

Comment: `I just have access` Don't you have your own account? And still, aliases are ignored in non-interactive programs.

Comment: @KamilCuk No I don't have my own account. I have limited access to a target machine